# How can this code be implemented in vue 2.0?

Tags: vue.js

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/?title={{obj.title}}" target="_blank"></a>
```

This code can work in vue 1.0,but in vue 2.0 it's return error

```
<a v-bind:href="http://en.wikipedia.org/?title=obj.title" target="_blank"></a>
```

This also cannot work,how can I modify the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-bind:href=" 'http://en.wikipedia.org/?title=' + obj.title "`

Basically, what is provided in [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) must return a valid Javascript value. In this case, it's String. Or it could also be Integer, Boolean, Function, Array, Object, ...

Comment: Hey, johnny, Jacob's answer is indeed correct (+1!). You should mark it as accepted: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/219205